# how to limit seekbar

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1, seekbar

I'd like to set max and minimum limits of **SeekBar** to 50 and 20 respectively.

[SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) has a direct option top provide max value, but how to set its minimum value to 20 rather than 0?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In SeekBar you **`can set only max value.`**

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/SeekBar01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:max="50"/>
```

And,
You cannot directly set the minimum value to the seekbar.

```
 SeekBar mSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);

    mSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
       public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
       {
            length_edit.setText(Integer.toString(progress + 20));
       }

      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    });
```

As you see min progress you can sum with min which I would like - in your case 20.

Comment: Well thanks for ur code,
it is working, except the fact that, the textview i am using to set the progrees value, is not showing and app gets crashed.

Comment: sorry dude, waz on leave, dats y didnt responded..i upvoted and aaccepeted d answer...

enjoy

Comment: @Paresh: Nice logic for set the minimum Value to seekbar. Great. . .

Comment: brother we can set text to any `view`

Comment: did you copied Romain's answer ;)

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Hope you have checked I posted this answer! And pls give me link of that answer.

Comment: @PareshMayani No offence. I was just kidding. Happy Androiding :)

Answer (score 25):

Set the max value to 30 and add 20 to the values you read from the SeekBar.

Comment: This is the only answer that does not have an effect on the desired maximum

Comment: Since API Level 26, you can use `setMin()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#setMin(int)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do this is to just limit it in the `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()` for your `SeekBar`.

First, you need to create field with min or default value. Then set this value when creating `SeekBar`:

```
private int fillDefault;
```

In `onCreateView()` of a `Fragment` or `onCreate` of an `Activity`:

```
fillDefault = 20;
fillSeekBar.setProgress(fillDefault);
```

Second, implement the listener for it:

```
fillSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // Notification that the progress level has changed.
            if (progress < fillDefault){
                seekBar.setProgress(fillDefault); // magic solution, ha
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // Notification that the user has started a touch gesture.
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // Notification that the user has finished a touch gesture.
        }
    });
```

It works. Simple and awesome:D

Comment: This solution is ideal when you set the padding left to 0dp and want to avoid that the thumb overlap the end of the seekbar i.e.:   if(progress == 0){
                    seekBar.setProgress(1);
                }

Answer (score 0):

For example;

```
 public static int LENGTH_MIN_VALUE = 20;
 public static int LENGTH_MAX_VALUE = 50;
 SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.passwordSeekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(LENGTH_MAX_VALUE);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(progress <= Constract.PASSWORD_LENGTH_MIN_VALUE){
                progress = Constract.PASSWORD_LENGTH_MIN_VALUE + progress;
            }

            String numberAsString = String.valueOf(progress);
            seekNumberView.setText(numberAsString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question here : [How to set seekbar min and max value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25118544/3612559).

With simple math you can set the min value, the max value and even the step of your seekbar.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```
seekBar.setMax(max_value-min_value);
```