# how to set seek bar in android with default values..?

Tags: android

The maximum value of `SeekBar` is 100 then How to set  a `Seekbar` values default  as 50 (starting at 50%). The seek bar will be start at 50.

I got a sample code but it will start at 0 to 100. 
Please answer me if you have any idea... 
Thank you.

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{
     private SeekBar bar; // declare seekbar object variable
     // declare text label objects
     private TextView textProgress,textAction;
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // load the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); // make seekbar object
    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // set seekbar listener.
    // since we are using this class as the listener the class is "this"

    // make text label for progress value
    textProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewProgress);
    // make text label for action
    textAction = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewAction);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // change progress text label with current seekbar value
    textProgress.setText("The value is: "+progress);
    // change action text label to changing
    textAction.setText("changing");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textAction.setText("starting to track touch");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(seekBar.getProgress());
    textAction.setText("ended tracking touch");     
    }

     }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set seekbar min and max value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762001/how-to-set-seekbar-min-and-max-value)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**in XML :**

```
android:progress="50" // or any other value
```

**in Java :**

```
mSeekbar.setProgress(50); // or any other value
```

and if you don't know what's the Max Value and just want to make it **50%**:

```
mSeekbar.setProgress(mSeekbar.getMax()/2);
```

Comment: @krishnan u welcome and glad I could help :) , kindly accept the answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://javatechig.com/android/android-seekbar-example) and here is how you can do

```
 seekBar.setMax(0);
 seekBar.setMax(100);
 seekBar.setProgress(50);
```

in xml you can do like this
   android:progress="50"

Comment: Shouldn't it be `seekBar.setMin(0);`?

Answer (score 0):

Set the MaxValue once before you set the progress value . In that way the system knows what proportion of the seekbar has to be colored.