# Setting minimum position for Seekbar in Android?

Tags: android, seekbar, brightness

Hey guys I'm trying to make a brightness bar in android and I want to set the position of the `thumb` to minimum like for example minimum value is 20, then the `thumb` should not get dragged before 20, that means 20 should be minimum, is this possible? I tried `seekbar.setMax(20);` but it's not what I want. Any help would be gladly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set seekbar min and max value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762001/how-to-set-seekbar-min-and-max-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {

            int MIN = 5;
            if (progress < MIN) {

                value.setText(" Time Interval (" + seektime + " sec)");
            } else {
                seektime = progress;
            }
            value.setText(" Time Interval (" + seektime + " sec)");

        }
    });
```