# Remove digits from seekBar android

Tags: android-seekbar

i have make 0 to 30 seekBar but i want to remove 0 to 9 digits from seekBar and it should be 10 to 30.

Please help me to remove these numbers from the seekbar.

```
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        pTxt.setText(progress);
    }
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow How to set seekbar min and max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762001/how-to-set-seekbar-min-and-max-value)

Comment: wow thank you so much.. this is working