# Minimum Value on Android SeekBar

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

How can I set the minimum value of a SeekBar?
I need a minimum of 435 and a max of 5435, but I don't know how to add the minimum value in this case.

My current code is here:

```
private void bindSeekAndEditText() {
    mSeekBar = (SeekBar) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.sb_value);
    mSeekBar.setMax(5435);
    mEtOtherValue = (EditText) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.et_value);
    mSeekBar.setProgress((int) (mSeekBar.getProgress() == 0 ? 5435 : mSeekBar.getProgress()));
    mEtOtherValue.addTextChangedListener(mEtOtherValue);
    mEtOtherValue.setText((double) (mSeekBar.getProgress() == 0 ? 5435 : mSeekBar.getProgress());
}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarStepChangeListener());
}

private final class OnSeekBarStepChangeListener implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        progress = ((int) Math.round(progress / 50)) * 50;
        mSeekBar.setProgress(progress);
        mEtOtherValue.setText(FormatingUtil.parseMoneyToBr((double) progress));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Cheap trick: set the max to (max - min) and when the value is changed, your true value will be (value + min)

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490951/how-to-limit-seekbar

Answer (score 0):

As of API Level 26 the method `setMin(int)` was added to class `android.widget.AbsSeekBar` [(see here)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#setMin(int)). Since `SeekBar` is a subclass of `AbsSeekBar`, this method can also be used in `SeekBar`.